# I need to open Drawer (DrawerNavigator) from NavigatorIOS button click, How can I do this?

Tags: react-native

I need to open side menu drawer(DrawerNavigator) from NavigatorIOS left button click, How can I do this? Getting error. 
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')

From Side menu user opened a screen that is Login Screen, from there user click on upper Left menu button that is on NavigatorIOS.

```
export default class NavigatorIOSApp extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        initialRoute={{
          component: LoginScreen,
          title: 'Sign In',
          passProps: {index: 1},
          leftButtonTitle: "Menu",
          onLeftButtonPress: () => {
            this.props.callMenu()
          },
        }}
        style={{flex: 1}}
      />
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends Component {

  callMenu()
    {
      alert("hi");
      //this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')
    }
   render() {
     return (
       <View style={styles.container}> Hello
       </view>
     )
   }
}
```

I have tried from

```
onLeftButtonPress: () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')
}
```

but gives error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')
```

Comment: try to use `callMenu()` as an arrow function to keep  the `this` from the component.

Comment: There is no prop for `navigate` in `NavigatorIOS` as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html#methods)